# Using F# type providers how do you implement a base constructor call as part of the constructor definition

Tags: f#, type-providers

What Im trying to do is create a provided type that calls its base constructor like this in C#:

```cs
public class SubclassController : BaseClass
{
    public SubclassController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {}
}
```

The closest I can currently get is this:

```cs
public sealed class SubclassController : BaseClass
{
    public SubclassController (IntPtr handle)
    {
        this;
        base..ctor (handle);
    }
```

Which although having the same functionality is not entirely the same.

The code I am using to build the ProvidedConstructor is as follows:

```
let providedConstructor = ProvidedConstructor([ProvidedParameter("handle", typeof<IntPtr>)])
let ctorInfo = typeof<SubclassController>.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Instance, null, [|typeof<IntPtr>|], null)
providedConstructor.BaseConstructorCall <- fun args -> ctorInfo, args
providedConstructor.InvokeCode <- fun args -> <@@ () @@>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually a bug in ProvidedTypes.fs which has now been fixed in the latest version.  It is available from the usual place at [codeplex](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/24356) thanks to @desco

So this code is actually all thats needed for a correctly formed base constructor call:

```
let providedConstructor = ProvidedConstructor([ProvidedParameter("handle", typeof<IntPtr>)])
let ctorInfo = typeof<SubclassController>.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public |||         BindingFlags.Instance, null, [|typeof<IntPtr>|], null)
providedConstructor.BaseConstructorCall <- fun args -> ctorInfo, args
providedConstructor.InvokeCode <- fun args -> <@@ () @@>
```